# Again Facebook Deferred link always return nil

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, facebook-ios-sdk, deferred

After asking `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` with an `authorized` status and then ask for `AppLinkUtility.fetchDeferredAppLink` always it return `nil` with this strange error:

**ATTrackingManager.AuthorizationStatus must be `authorized` for deferred deep linking to work. Read more at:         https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency**

It doesn't make sense because the status is `authorized`

#### Steps to Reproduce

What are the steps necessary to reproduce this issue?
Very simple to describe:

1. Login to your facebook
2. Then Click https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper
3. Select an app you want to test from drop down
4. Hit submit
5. At the bottom you will find 'Deep Link Tester' under Developer
   Tools.
6. Hit 'Test Deep Link' and in the dialog you can enter your deep
   link.
7. Select both 'Send Notification' and 'Send Deferred' check marks.
8. Then you will get a notification to your facebook app.
9. Tap in the notification and it is opened the App Store
10. Install the App through Xcode

#### Code Samples & Details

Then in my code I tried all this variants:

I tried this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Set the trackings to true in test mode
        Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)
        Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
        Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true

        // Initialize the Facebook SDK
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false
        Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = false
        Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = false
}
```

Then on the primary ViewController:

```
class SomePrimaryViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupUI()
    }

    @available(iOS 14.5.1, *)
    private func presentTransparencyMode() {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
            
             switch status
            {
            case .authorized:
                
                // Tracking authorization dialog was shown
                // and we are authorized
                print("Authorized")
                
                // Now that we are authorized we can get the IDFA
                print(ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier)
                
                // Get the Deferred link
                 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    self.setupDefferedLink()
                }

            case .denied:
                // Tracking authorization dialog was
                // shown and permission is denied
                print("Denied")
            case .notDetermined:
                // Tracking authorization dialog has not been shown
                print("Not Determined")
            case .restricted:
                print("Restricted")
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown")
            }
        }
        
    }

    private func setupDefferedLink() {
     
        // Set the trackings to true in test mode
        Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
        Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
        Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true

        let id = ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString
        let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "/971082983006874/activities", parameters: ["event": "DEFERRED_APP_LINK",
                                                                                          "advertiser_id": id,
                                                                                          "application_tracking_enabled": "1",
                                                                                          "advertiser_tracking_enabled": "1"], httpMethod: .post)
        
        request.start { [unowned self] connection, result, error in
            if let result = result as? NSDictionary {
                print(result as Any)
                // It prints a dictionary with a key `success` with  value `true` 
                // and nothing about the url
            }
        }
        
        AppLinkUtility.initialize()
        AppLinkUtility.fetchDeferredAppLink { (url, error) in
            if let url = url {
                print(url)
            }
            print(error as Any)
            // It prints:
            // ATTrackingManager.AuthorizationStatus must be `authorized` for deferred deep linking to work. Read more at:         https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency
           // That is an Error of the SDK, because the permission has been granted
        }
        
    }

}
```

No matter which variant you try, the result is always the same, `url = nil`